# My code segfaults on the second call to the STL::stack::push()

Tags: c++, stl

In the code below, which uses ncurses, so no printf, I get an interesting segfault

```
// Returns the path constructed from A*
void Creature::returnPath(struct Tile* currentTile){
  // Declarations
  int DEBUG = 0;
  int stepX;
  int stepY;
  int combo;
  while(currentTile->parent != NULL){
    mvprintw(12 + DEBUG ,0, "in while %i", currentTile->parent);
    refresh();
    stepX = currentTile->x;
    stepY = currentTile->y;
    // The path data structure consists of a int split so xxxyyy
    combo = (stepX * 1000) + stepY;
    mvprintw(12 + DEBUG, 20, "HERE %i %i", &path, &(this->path));
    refresh();
    path.push(combo);
    currentTile = currentTile->parent;
    DEBUG++;
   } 
}
```

On the second push, my code segfaults,  I know this because I have swapped the mvprintw()and refresh() below it and nothing is output

Why would it segfault on the second call???

The path stack is a member of an object listed below

```
class Creature{
  public:
    // The constructor that takes (x,y) as well as a char representation
    // of the creature to be blitted
    Creature(int x, int y, char blit);
    // Draws the creature on the screen at its current position
    int drawCreature(WINDOW* window);
    // Takes one step 
    int step(Map* map);
    int move(int x, int y, Map* map);
    void returnPath(struct Tile* currentTile);
    std::stack<int> path;
    int x;
    int y;
  private:
    char blit;
};
```

The creature is malloc'd here

```
int Map::addCreature(int x, int y, char type){
  // TODO: have a creature free command
  Creature* creaturePoint = (Creature*) malloc(sizeof(Creature));
  *creaturePoint = Creature(x, y, 'r');
  creatureList[y][x].push_front(creaturePoint);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you run it through the debugger and see what the traceback shows?

Comment: Using `malloc` and then assigning to the memory location, as you are doing in the `addCreature` function, is not a valid way to create an object of non-trivial type.  Why don't you just use `new`? Or better yet, don't use pointers in the first place.  Unless you need run-time polymorphism, in which case you should use a smart pointer.

Comment: I believe what @BenjaminLindley highlighted is actually the reason for your crash.  Try replacing the line with the `malloc` and the line after it with `creaturePoint = new Creature(x, y, 'r');`  Also, be sure when you're getting rid of it, to `delete` it, not `free` it.

Comment: You cannot malloc an object like that. You have to use the new operator. I also suspect that the segfault is the least problem with your code. You need to know about RAII and the rule of five, and rewrite with those in mind.

Comment: @JoeZ  That worked, if you submit it as an answer I can accept it!  Thanks.  As an aside, why does malloc not work here?

Comment: There could be any number of reasons, depending on `stack<>`'s implementation.  For example it may have used a move-assignment operation, which typically _exchanges_ storage with the object it's moving on top of, for example.  The object you were assigning to was allocated by `malloc()` though, and so was not properly initialized.  That means that the `stack<>` on the right-hand side of the assignment was interacting with an uninitialized `stack<>` on the left-hand side and ending up in an inconsistent state.

Comment: malloc does not create an object, it just allocates memory.  To create an object, you need to call the constructor, which `new` does.  If you haven't created an object, then it is invalid to call member functions (such as the assignment operator, which you are doing) on the memory location. Note that the problem is *not* the call to malloc, it is the call to the assignment operator on the memory location, because there is no object there.  It is, however, possible to create an object in the location which was allocated by malloc, using a different form of `new`, called placement new.

Comment: @dakillakan : Posted as an answer.  Also, @BenjaminLindley is correct that `malloc()` _can_ be made to work, if you need to make it work for some reason.  Placement-new is generally meant for custom allocators, and I highly doubt you need one here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocating an object with `malloc()` does not initialize the object.

Subsequently copying an object over the allocated storage results in undefined behavior, as the object being copied now has the opportunity to interact with the *uninitialized* object created by `malloc()`.  This can wreak havoc in a variety of ways, all dependent on the exact details of the objects involved.

For example, the compiler expects to destruct the object being copied over, but that object isn't actually initialized.  With move semantics, the left and right-hand objects could interact (say, to move or exchange storage), but the object on the left-hand side isn't in a consistent state because it was never initialized.

To correct your code, replace these two lines:

```
  Creature* creaturePoint = (Creature*) malloc(sizeof(Creature));
  *creaturePoint = Creature(x, y, 'r');
```

with this one line:

```
  Creature* creaturePoint = new Creature(x, y, 'r');
```

Also, when you deallocate this object, be sure to use `delete`, not `free()`.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder who downvoted?  I'm happy to hear your concern.